# "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" Error on react app only on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I have react app and its run well using `yarn start` on dev and use vite. When I deploy using app service on digitalocean, the deployment result success but when I open my app it just showing white blank page and the log result show "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".

I already follow:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12174
- my javascript is enabled on browser

but still no luck.

I try to deploy react app on digitalocean app service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, and here what I do to solve this:

1. Vite by default only listen to local host "127.0.0.1" so I need to add `host: true` to `vite.config.js`
2. Another problem is from my DO settings, by default it will generate route when we create app service, so I need to change to "/" on routes settings.

Note: I use `web service` type instead of `static` because for me I need to see runtime logs and sometimes I need to use console.

Hope this can help if someone get the same situation.